# How to setup relationship between 3 Model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know there is a lot of questions similar to this but I couldn't find a better answer.
So let's get to the point.

> I have 3 tables with Model showing below:
>
> ```
> //******* academic_years table**************
> Schema::create('academic_years', function (Blueprint $table) {
>         $table->id();
>         $table->string('year')->unique();
>     });
> //************classrooms table*************
> Schema::create('classrooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
>         $table->id();
>         $table->string('name')->unique();
>         $table->string('slug');
>     });
> //**********faculties table***************
> Schema::create('faculties', function (Blueprint $table) {
>       $table->id();
>       $table->string('name')->unique();
>       $table->string('slug');
>     });
> ```

I want to have a many to many relationships between these Model:

1. ONE academic year(2020) has many classrooms
2. Each classroom for that year(2020) can have more than ONE faculties
3. A faculty can belongs to many classrooms.

I would like to setup a relationship that will allows to return the list on all years with their classrooms and faculties that belong to each of the classroom.

For example: I want to return Year:2020 with classrooms: Grad-1 with faculty-1, Grad-2 with faculty-1

My pivot table looks like this. Or maybe someone can suggest a better approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out on my way. Maybe this is not the best approach but I least took me somewhere. If someone has a better approach or there is some issues with this approach please feel free to share it here.

I setup the relationship as follow:

```
//*********ACADEMICYEAR MODEL *************

public function classrooms()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\Classroom', 'academic_year_classroom);
}


//***********FACULTY MODEL ********************** //
public function classrooms()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\Classroom', 'academic_year_classroom');
}


//********CLASSROOM MODEL **************
public function academicyears()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\AcademicYear');
}

public function faculties()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\Faculty', 'academic_year_classroom', 'classroom_id', 'faculty_id');
}
```

> ```
> //1. I was able to return the records for a single year with it classrooms and faculties assigned to that classroom as follow:
>
> public function show($id)
> {
>   return $year = AcademicYear::with(['classrooms', 'classrooms.faculties' => function ($q) use($id) {
>     $q->where('academic_year_id', $id);
>   }])->findOrFail($id);
> }
> ```
>
> I was also able to return the list of all the years with classrooms for each year and the faculties that were assigned to each of the classrooms as follow:

```
   public function index()
  {
   // First I retrieve all the Year IDs as an array
    $yearID = AcademicYear::pluck('id')->toArray();

    foreach($yearID as $yr) {
      $year = AcademicYear::with(['classrooms', 'classrooms.faculties' => function ($q) use($yr) {
        $q->whereIn('academic_year_id', [$yr]);
      }])->orderBy('year', 'DESC')->get();
    }
      return $year;
  }
```

Again, if you have a better way to approach this, please share with us. And if this answer was helpful please vote it so that it can help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest addiung foreign keys to classrooms and faculties tables.

Afterwards you need to assign add relations between each model, belongsToMany() and hasMany().

Once defined you can use `with()` and `whereHas` to fetch relevant data.

To fetch all classrooms and faculties you'd use:

```
AcademicYear::with('classroom.faculty')
  ->where('year', 2020);
```

I want to return Year:2020 with classrooms: Grad-1 with faculty-1, Grad-2 with faculty-1

```
AcademicYear::with('classroom.faculty')
  ->whereHas('classroom', function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('name', ['Grad-1', 'Grad-2']);
      ->whereHas('faculty', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'faculty-1');
      });
  })
  ->where('year', 2020);
```

You should also be able to do something like below (not sure how query would look for that):

```
AcademicYear::with([
    'classroom' => function($query) {
      $query->whereIn('name', ['Grad-1', 'Grad-2']);
    },
    'faculty' => function($query) {
      $query->where('name', 'faculty-1');
    })
  ])
  ->where('year', 2020);
```

reference - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

And... if you are to stick with the same structure you can define same relations, hasManyThrough, but via your pivot table.

---

Update:

One other thing that you can do, is add a Model for your Pivot table and defining relationships between pivot and your other models.

I want to return Year:2020 with classrooms: Grad-1 with faculty-1, Grad-2 with faculty-1

```
MyPivotModel::with([
    'academic_year', 
    'classroom', 
    'faculty'
  ])
  ->whereHas('classroom', function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('name', ['Grad-1', 'Grad-2']); 
  })
  ->whereHas('faculty', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'faculty-1');
  })
  ->whereHas('academic_year', function($query) {
    $query->where('year', 2020);
  });
```

Comment: thank you so much for response. I could add foreign keys on classrooms and faculties table, but the reason I don't want to do it this way is that classroom will be assigned to multiple academic year, same thing with faculties. I want to keep the record of all the academic years. If I had  foreign keys to those tables, means that if I have the classroom_id foreign key in faculties table, it will reference to a single classroom and same thing  with classrooms table. **I want to have a faculty assigned to multiple classrooms and classroom assigned to different year**

Comment: Ok, cool. Another way is to use manyToMany. That way you’d be able to utilise sync() and attach()/detach() method that come with Laravel. One thing to be aware is that MySQL May behave oddly when indexing columns that have null values.